# VB.NET 1D array access using 2 indices

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

Trying to port over some legacy VB.NET code to C# and running into syntax issues with array indexing.

Within a VB method, called, Get_Coverage_Percentage, is a line of code that looks like this:

```
 Dim RS_Activation_List = Get_Activation_List(Company_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, 0)
```

where RS_Activation_List was initialized in method Get_Activation_List as

```
 Dim Activation_List(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count) As Activation_List
```

Based on my current understanding of VB.NET syntax, that above translated to a 1D array.
However, later in Get_Coverage_Percentage, is a line that accesses Activation_List array as follows:

```
  RS_Prorated_Activation = FormatNumber(RS_Activation_List(RS_Sum_Activation, 5), 2)
```

How can one be accessing a 1D array using 2 indices?  Activation_List itself is a simple structure that is defined as follows:

```
  Structure Activation_List
        Dim Mobile_ID As Integer
        Dim Radio_Address As Double
        Dim Activation_Date As Date
        Dim Pro_Rated_Fee As Integer
        Dim Sum_Pro_Rated_Fee As Integer
    End Structure
```

VB pro, what am I looking at here?

**Update: **
Method *Get_Activation_List* looks like this, with some parts taken out:

```
 Public Function Iridium_Get_Activation_List(ByVal Company_ID, ByVal Start_Date, ByVal End_Date, ByVal Access_Fee) As Array
        Dim vNumOfDaysInMonth = Get_Number_Of_Day_In_Month(Start_Date)
        Dim SQL = "SELECT * from assMobileRadio;"

        Dim drDataRow As DataRow
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetData(SQL)
        Iridium_Get_Activation_List = Nothing
        Dim Activation_List(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count) As Activation_List  
        Dim vSumofProrated = 0
        Dim vRow = 0
        For Each drDataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
             'missing code
            vRow = vRow + 1
        Next
        Return Activation_List
    End Function
```

and yes, the code does not compile.

Comment: What you've got is uncompilable code.  If everything is as you describe that won't compile.  Somewhere in your code is something other than what you've described. Given your proclivity to give the same name to different objects you've probably got a subroutine named the same

Comment: @tinstaafl, I am not original author so I am also guess here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is declaring a new variable array of type `Activation_List`

```
Dim Activation_List(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count) As Activation_List
```

This line declares a different variable of a different type:

```
Dim RS_Activation_List = Get_Activation_List(Company_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, 0)
```

We don't know what type this is from your code, but given this line works ok it is a 2d array of some custom type:

```
RS_Prorated_Activation = FormatNumber(RS_Activation_List(RS_Sum_Activation, 5), 2)
```

Hover over `RS_Activation` in VS and see what type it says it is. Also make sure you have Option Strict On.

Comment: I just added an update.  Array of type Activation_List is being defined and returned in a method Get_Activation_List.  I get no "Dim RS_Activation_List as object", hovering over the variable RS_Activation_List.   Cannot say if line works as code does not compile.  Agreed something is funny.  Where do I enable Strict mode?

Comment: You can set it in the project properties in the Compile section: Option Strict = On

Comment: Thanks, found Option Strict but now project has 102 errors!  With option off, project compiles successfully :)

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean there is something wrong! If options strict is off it could be masking a runtime error.

Comment: @MattWilko, there must be a runtime error occuring.  Will need to get project executing to confirm but turning on strict is a good idea.  It is exposing several other problems, which is why the project is being re-written.